# SMTP does not work using web

Tags: .net, smtp, gmail-api

I have this code for sending mail using web, but im getting error: 
"The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required"

Can anyone help me please?

```
try
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();
        mm.From = new MailAddress(email.Value.ToString());
        mm.To.Add("tomerboxinggym@gmail.com");
        mm.Subject = "contact: " + subject.Value;

        mm.Body = "email:" + email.Value + "\n " + "message: " + message.Value;


        mm.Priority = MailPriority.High;


        SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
        sc.EnableSsl = true;
        sc.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("tomerboxinggym@gmail.com", "boxing123!");//user name & pass
        sc.Send(mm);


        email.Disabled = true;
        email.Value = "";
        subject.Disabled = true;
        subject.Value = "";
        message.Disabled = true;
        message.Value = "";
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

    LabeSuc.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    LabeSuc.Text = ex.Message; ;
}
```

Comment: How about just "tomerboxinggym" , w/o @gmail as the username? An SMTP server will be quite literal about such details.

Comment: thanks for your reply. it doesnt work..
is ther anything else?

Comment: No, but do investigate. Run it with an username/pw that you know are wrong and see if you get the same error. Same for Portnumber and EnableSSL. And check the settings from @Easy's post.

Answer (score 1):

You'll do much better off using Oauth2 for authentication.  Then you can get an access token that's long-lived and only scoped to certain privileges.  Rather than passing around a password, which understandably triggers security alarms and is increasingly difficult to use (Google is phasing out simple use of passwords when more secure methods of authentication exist).

Oauth2 + Gmail (REST HTPT) API seems a better option here than Password + SMTP MSA especially if you're "using web" means running from a browser/extension/etc.

Answer (score 0):

Enter here and choose 'enable': https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps.

You will see the explanations there.